# Using pyramid authentication with pyramid

Tags: python, authorization, pyramid

In the pyramid documentation, the Sqlalchemy Dispatch Tutorial uses dummy data in `security.py`. I needed to use mysql data so I implemented it like this:

**My Login Code**

```
@view_config(route_name='login', renderer='json',permission='view')
def user_login(request):
    session = DBSession
    username = request.params['username']
    password = request.params['password']
    sha = hashlib.md5()
    sha.update(password)
    password = sha.digest().encode('hex')
    user = session.query(Users).filter(and_(Users.username==username,Users.password ==password)).count()   
    if(user != 0):
        headers = remember(request, username)
        return HTTPFound(location = '/index/',
                             headers =headers)
    else:
        print "error"
```

The above makes the system remember username that will be used in `security.py`. Below, I use this to get the group the user is in.

```
from .models import (
    DBSession,
    Users,
    )

def groupfinder(userid, request): 
    session = DBSession()
    for instance in session.query(Users).filter(Users.username==userid):
        group = 'group:'+instance.group  
        lsth = {'userid':[group]}
        return lsth.get  ('userid')
```

Is this the best way to use pyramid authorization?

Comment: I have to say, this code is a really good brief introduction to how SQLAlchemy authentication works (or can work).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have the idea right.

Your groupfinder is broken right now. Notice you have a for-loop with a return statement inside. The groupfinder should return **at least** an empty list `[]` if the user is valid. Only return `None` if the user is invalid.

Also an md5 of the password is pretty crappy these days. Look at the cryptacular or passlib libraries for performing a cryptographic hash instead via bcrypt.