# Pyramid authorization being bypassed

Tags: python, mysql, authentication, pyramid

I have just added authorization to my pyramid application according to [the docs](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki2/authorization.html#seeing-our-changes).  At this time the app only displays info.

I will also obtain my login information from MySQL, so I have implemented something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171519/using-pyramid-authentication-with-pyramid).

However, its not quite working as it should, and I don't know how to fix it:

After I logout, I can bypass the entire login by just entering the target page URL. It seems to me that its not 'forgetting' the login.  It also does not redirect to the login page when I enter the url directly.

Here is my `views.py:`

**target page:**

```
@view_config(route_name='monitor', 
        renderer='monitor:templates/monitor.mak', 
        permission='view'
        )
def monitor(request):

    oEntry_Logins = DBSession.query(Login).order_by(Login.id)
    oEntry_Alerts = DBSession.query(Alert).order_by(Alert.id)

    return {
                'oEntry_Logins' : oEntry_Logins,
                'oEntry_Alerts'   : oEntry_Alerts,
                'logged_in' : request.authenticated_userid,
        }
```

**login/logout:**

```
@view_config(route_name='login', renderer='templates/login.pt')
@forbidden_view_config(renderer='templates/login.pt')
def login(request):


    login_url = request.route_url('login')
    referrer = request.url
    if referrer == login_url:
        referrer = '/' # never use the login form itself as came_from
    came_from = request.params.get('came_from', referrer)
    message = ''
    login = ''
    password = ''
    if 'form.submitted' in request.params:
        login = request.params['login']
        password = request.params['password']

        user = DBSession.query(User).filter(login==User.name).filter(password==User.password).count()  #DBSession
        if(user != 0):  #DBSession

            headers = remember(request, login)
            return HTTPFound(location = came_from,
                            headers = headers)
        message = 'Failed login'

    return dict(
        message = message,
        url = request.application_url + '/login',
        came_from = came_from,
        login = login,
        password = password,
        )

#logout view
@view_config(route_name='logout')
def logout(self):

    request = self.request

    headers = forget(request)
    return HTTPFound(location = request.route_url('login'),
                    headers = headers)
```

**and here is my models file:**

```
...
class RootFactory(object):
    __acl__ = [ (Allow, Everyone, 'view'),
                (Allow, 'group:editors', 'edit') ]
    def __init__(self, request):
        pass
```

**and my security.py file:**

```
from .models import (
    DBSession,
    User,
    )

def groupfinder(userid, request): 
    session = DBSession()
    for instance in session.query(User).filter(User.name==userid):

        group = 'group:'  #all are simply part of the same group
        lsth = {'userid':[group]}
    return lsth.get  ('userid')
```

At the moment, for testing purposes, the passwords are still stored as plaintext in a mysql database.

How do I make this code work as it should?

Comment: What does your ACL list look like?  Is the 'view' permission open to everyone, or is it restricted to only authenticated users?  Finally, if you open up a new browser window in "incognito mode" and go to the target page, do you get redirected to the login there or does it go directly to the page, too?

Comment: It goes directly to the page, nothing at all seems to get redirected.  Perhaps I imagined it redirecting.  It is open to everyone I think, check updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more request then - can you post your `groupfinder` function, too?

So what looks like is happening is `permission='view'` means that view is open to `Everyone`. If you change it to `permission='edit'` then it would only be available to members of the "editors" group, but that also depends on what is returned from the groupfinder().

Alternatively, I think if you use `(Allow, Authenticated, 'edit')`, change your permission to 'edit', and it would only allow you to access it if you were logged in.  You might have to add `from pyramid.security import Authenticated` to your import statements as well.

Comment: O' you wizzard!  Groupfinder is added to the question.  The target page now redirects to the login page in private browsing, and after login jumps to the straight to the right page.  Logout also does what it should now.